# MySQL Using MAX ignores WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a strange problem where I am using MAX on a primary key and the query is ignoring my WHERE clause.

```
$isWorking= 0;
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT versionId, isFinished FROM users WHERE userId = :userId");
$q->bindParam(':userId',$userId);
$q->execute();
$qr = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($q->rowCount() > 0){
  foreach($qr as $row){
       if($row['isFinished'] == '1'){
           $isWorking = 0;
       }else{
           $isWorking = 1;
       }
   }return $isWorking;
 }
```

In the table there is literally only one entry.

```
versionId: 44 isFinished : 1  userId : 20
```

When I execute the above query, and supply various userId including '20', I get `$isWorking = 0` for everyone. When I change the query to this:

```
"SELECT MAX(versionId)...
```

I get `$isWorking = 0` for the supplied id, but `"1"` for everyone else!!

How can this be? It is ignoring my `WHERE` clause and any userId supplied runs the query...

Comment: You're talking about "everyone else" and "various userID" which implies there are multiple rows in the table but you also say "In the table there is literally only one entry." Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Please supply table definition, preferably in an http://sqlfiddle.com